# How to show a message to the user if camera is already in-use by another application

Tags: android, android-camera

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    boolean error = false;
    try {
    Camera = Camera.open(1);
  } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
    error = true;
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

changed code here.

To show the alert dialog message if camera is already opened in other application.

```
if(error){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Camera in use ")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                finish();
            }
        })
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .show();

    }
```

used finish() here, just to avoid crash of the application.

```
    finish();

     if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.startPreview();
           mPreview.setCamera(mCamera);

       }
    }



 public void finish() {
        ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView();
        view.removeAllViews();
        super.finish();
    }
```

It is entering the if condition, but it not showing alert dialog. Instead it crashes the application. But when I use finish() after the if statement is closed. It just closes the application without crashing.

E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked I'm getting this error when application closed.

How to avoid this error and show the user a dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a leaked `Window` because you are not dismissing the `Dialog` before the `Activity` finishes. If the `Camera` is in use by another `Application` and said app is out of scope, then it bad practice from the developer of that app; system resources should be released as soon as possible.

Comment: Side note: I believe if you have a "Flashlight" enabled on your phone while you attempt to access the camera you get the same issue. I wish Google's default camera would provide a more user friendly error than "Camera Unavailable" until I figured it couldn't obtain the flash LED resource.

Comment: I agree with this, but I don't want to crash my application, because of another application.

Comment: I application only uses front camera. So I'm not using flashlight.